# PyQGIS memory issues

Tags: pyqgis, memory, keyerror

I have some big problems with the memory usage of my standalone PyQgis script based on QGis 2.18 and run on ubuntu/linux (happens also on Windows 10 though).
I will document it very precisely using memory profiler module.

It basically seems like QgsGeometry and other QGIS objects aren't deleted properly or in some cases memory is allocated without an obvious reason (background tasks?).

Do I explicitly need to call the destructor on Qgs Objects like QgsGeometry etc?

If so, how do I do it exactly?

#### importing and starting QgsApplication

```
import sys
import qgis
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4 import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
qgs = QgsApplication(sys.argv, False)
qgs.initQgis()
```

#### memory profiler ouput

```
39   89.312 MiB   89.312 MiB   @profile
40                             def main():
41   89.312 MiB    0.000 MiB       f = '/media/sven/Dual_data/ma/site_search_program/gis_data/basis_dlm/gew01_f.shp'
42                             
43   93.023 MiB    3.711 MiB       layer_l = QgsVectorLayer(f, 'file', 'ogr')
44  168.070 MiB   75.047 MiB       geom_dict = {feat.id(): QgsGeometry(feat.geometry()) for feat in layer_l.getFeatures()}
45  168.078 MiB    0.008 MiB       del layer_l
46  168.078 MiB    0.000 MiB       size = 0.0
47  168.078 MiB    0.000 MiB       for id, geom in geom_dict.iteritems():
48  168.078 MiB    0.000 MiB           size += sys.getsizeof(geom)
49  168.078 MiB    0.000 MiB       print 'size geom dict', size/1024/1024
50  168.078 MiB    0.000 MiB       print 'input count', len(geom_dict)
#print outputs:
#size geom dict 2.96440124512 [MB]
#input count 20450
```

Why do the geometries have a size of 1.4 MB but 75 MB is used? Maybe deleting the layer will help? - No it actually costs memory? (Yeah not allot - still..)

```
51  168.078 MiB   -3.828 MiB       geom_dict = {id: geom for id, geom in geom_dict.iteritems() if id < 100}
52  164.250 MiB   -3.828 MiB       size = 0.0
53  164.102 MiB   -0.148 MiB       for id, geom in geom_dict.iteritems():
54  164.102 MiB    0.000 MiB           size += sys.getsizeof(geom)
55  164.102 MiB    0.000 MiB       print 'size shrunk geom dict', size/1024/1024
56  164.102 MiB    0.000 MiB       print 'input count', len(geom_dict)
#print outputs:
#size shrunk geom dict 0.0144958496094
#input count 100
```

Lets delete most of the geoms and look at the memory usage: Yeah we free up some memory but by far not the share of 75 MB that should be expected - still more than to be expected when comparing sizes with sys module though.

```
57  164.855 MiB    0.754 MiB       buffered_geoms = {id: geom.buffer(100, 5) for id, geom in geom_dict.iteritems()}
58  164.855 MiB    0.000 MiB       del geom_dict
59  164.855 MiB    0.000 MiB       geom_dict = buffered_geoms
60  164.855 MiB    0.000 MiB       size = 0.0
61  164.855 MiB    0.000 MiB       for id, geom in geom_dict.iteritems():
62  164.855 MiB    0.000 MiB           size += sys.getsizeof(geom)
63  164.855 MiB    0.000 MiB       print 'buffered geoms size', size/1024/1024
#print outputs:
#buffered geoms size 0.0144958496094
```

Deleting the dict of geometries should free up its memory usage, shouldn't it? It doesn't apparently.

Note this propably isn't necessary anymore and the code gets a bit messy - but while I am at it - this is my real problem:
Afterwards I want to unit the buffered geoms to calculate the area without calculating overlapping geometries.
As said the code gets a bit messy - I hope it is understandable. I guess it will be the same problem as above. With big input layers this runs into using up all my memory and freezing my computer. As far as I understand I am not creating any permanent new Objects, even freeing up used ones, but memory usage rises and rises (Note not visible in memory profiler cause of small input/only last iteration memory usage is noted, you can still see rising memory usage though)

#### Calculating area of buffered geoms after uniting them

```
65                                 #calculating area of buffered geoms
66                                 #create spatial Index
67  164.855 MiB    0.000 MiB       spaInd = QgsSpatialIndex()
68  164.855 MiB    0.000 MiB       feat = QgsFeature()
69  164.855 MiB    0.000 MiB       for nr, geom in geom_dict.iteritems():
70  164.855 MiB    0.000 MiB           feat.setFeatureId(nr)
71  164.855 MiB    0.000 MiB           feat.setGeometry(geom)
72  164.855 MiB    0.000 MiB           feat.setValid(True)
73  164.855 MiB    0.000 MiB           spaInd.insertFeature(feat)
74  164.855 MiB    0.000 MiB       print 'spaInd size', sys.getsizeof(spaInd)/1024/1024
75  164.855 MiB    0.000 MiB       size = 0
76  164.855 MiB    0.000 MiB       ges_area = 0
77                                 #unit intersecting polys to calculate area
78                                 #should be no permanent objects - resulting geometries arent saved
79                                 #it moreover should free up memory with deleting input geometries - it doesnt though - it runs into memory issues
80                                 #very fast with big layers until freezing of pc
81  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB       for geom_id in geom_dict.keys():
82  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB           try:
83  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB               geom = geom_dict[geom_id]
84  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB               skip = {geom_id}
85  165.301 MiB    0.445 MiB               abs_geom = geom.geometry()
86  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB               bboxes = [abs_geom.boundingBox()]
87  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB               united = False
88  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB               unit = True
89                                         #cause of enlarged polygon we need to do this repetitively until there are no geoms intersecting
90  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB               while unit:
91  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                   unit = False
92  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                   new_bboxes = []
93                                             # intersection tests done with engine for performance
94  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                   engine = QgsGeometry.createGeometryEngine(abs_geom)
95  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                   engine.prepareGeometry()
96  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                   intersecting_geoms = [abs_geom]
97  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                   for bbox in bboxes:
98  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                       ids = spaInd.intersects(bbox)
99                                                 #geometries arent replaced so already combined geoms are saved in skip and not done again
100                                                 #delted geometries are also not used
101  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                       ids = [i for i in ids if i not in skip and i in geom_dict]
102  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                       if len(ids) >= 100:
103                                                     print 'uniting still working len ids', geom_id
104  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                       for id in ids:
105  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                           abs_geom_in = geom_dict[id].geometry()
106  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                           if engine.intersects(abs_geom_in):
107  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                               unit = True
108                                                         #use bounding boxes of intersecting geoms for new spaInd requests to not use extremly large
109                                                         #bbox of resulting geometry if e.g. a river network is combined
110  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                               new_bboxes.append(abs_geom_in.boundingBox())
111  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                               intersecting_geoms.append(abs_geom_in)
112  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                               skip.add(id)
113  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                   if unit:
114  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                       bboxes = new_bboxes
115  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                       united = True
116  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                       abs_geom = engine.combine(intersecting_geoms)
117                             
118  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB               if not united:
119                                             #make an independent deep copy of QgsAbstractGeometryV2 Object if it didnt get created by engine
120                                             #otherwise SegFaults will happen - also note that making a deep copy of the QgsGeometry object
121                                             #will still not prevent SegFaults
122  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                   abs_geom = type(abs_geom)(abs_geom)
123  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB               geom = QgsGeometry(abs_geom)
124  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB               ges_area += geom.area()
125                                         # united_geom_dict[geom_id] = geom
126                                         # if not len(united_geom_dict) % 1000:
127                                         #     print 'uniting still working len geom dict'
128  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB               for id2 in skip:
129                                             # free memory
130  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB                   del geom_dict[id2]
131  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB           except KeyError:
132  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB               pass
133  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB       print 'ges_area', ges_area
134  165.301 MiB    0.000 MiB       print 'empty geom dict', geom_dict
#print outputs:
#ges_area 4710204.56653
#empty geom dict {}
```

#### Pretty long... short tl/dr:

QgsGeometry and other Qgs objects use a lot more memory than to be expected by measuring their size with sys.getsizeof(). Also they don't seem to be destroyed correctly. Do I need to call the destructor explicitly and if so, how do I do that? I thought deleting with del (and being the only reference) should do that.

Also can someone explain the destructor usage to me? According to https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsGeometry.html#aacaf2856a136d270dcf274649439adf7 it should be geom.~QgsGeometry()? This doesn't work though.

Comment: Remember, Python has a GC and `del` only deletes the reference; it will be actually deleted at GC time.  Your 75 MB is the size of the dictionary, with the size of any keys and hashes (I believe, I cannot remember it does shallow or deep count).  Are you building embedded?  75MB isn't much to fret over; don't early optimize, just get it working first; or... have fun exploring!

Comment: I dont think I am overoptimizing, when I try to not let my Pc freeze while running my script. 75 MB is the size of a small layer, with a big layer it is easily 500MB. Also I can't iterate over geometries doing normal calculations (see last part) without creating permanent Objects, because memory does not get freed up and all memory is consumed. Also gc does tell me there is nothing to delete using forcing garbage collection from https://pymotw.com/2/gc/. Also no it's not the dictionary that takes up 75 mb, how ineffective would that be? The dictionary itself is smaller than 1MB.

Comment: freeing memory does not mean it is released to the OS. Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455048/releasing-memory-in-python)