# Using destructors in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, memory

Related to my Problem described in [PyQGIS memory issues](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283597/pyqgis-memory-issues), I'd like to try using destructors for QgsGeometry and other classes. I dont get how to use them though.

According to https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsGeometry.html#aacaf2856a136d270dcf274649439adf7 it should be:
geom.~QgsGeometry()

This is invalid syntax though. Are they explicitly callable at all? And if so - how to do it?

(Qgis 2.18)

Comment: `~QgsGeometry()` is supposed to be used in C++, Python's `del` or `gc` won't solve your problem?